# How to draw over a picture in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo-camera

I have an app that uses expo-camera to take a picture. I would like to implement a function that would let user to draw over a taken picture. What is the best way to achieve this?

What have I tried?

- react-native-sketch-canvas (looks like this component is no longer supported)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [React native Skia](https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/) from shopify

Here is a [blog](https://medium.com/react-native-rocket/building-a-hand-drawing-app-with-react-native-skia-and-gesture-handler-9797f5f7b9b4) that you may find useful

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these :

1. [@flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas) (Last publish - a month ago)
2. [@lighthouse/react-native-sketch-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lighthouse/react-native-sketch-canvas) (Last publish - 9 months ago)
3. [react-native-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-canvas) (Last publish - a year ago)